# Is there a reasonable BBCode library for Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have been playing around with both [bb-ruby](https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/bb-ruby) and [rbbcode](https://github.com/jarrett/rbbcode) and have found both unusable in various ways.

Before waste my time rolling my own, are there any other libraries worth trying?

Comment: You might want to mention why bb-ruby and rbbcode are unusable.

Comment: It is fairly irrelevant to the actual question, but they can't handle nested quotes(especially bb-ruby) and lists properly and the source for both is such a mess. Please don't say "just fix it" because that excuse is what makes many RubyGems worthless. Too many gems are poorly written and not kept up to date. If I just fixed it myself whenever I came across a somewhat broken gem that I could otherwise use, I wouldn't actually be able to work on my projects. At least if I roll my own, I know it will fit my needs exactly and takes no more work then trying to figure out and work around odd code.

Comment: Wow a neg for asking a legitimate question.

Comment: Personally I dislike BBCode. Is markdown out of the question?

Comment: Could we know what you finally decided to do? Did you use a gem in particular? If so, which one? Thanks! ^^

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [bbcoder](http://github.com/asceth/bbcoder).  I should note that it was written by me because I found other bbcode gems to be lacking or based on regex's which didn't work too well in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a new version of [rbbcode](https://github.com/jarrett/rbbcode). It's waaaay better than the original. For starters, it's based on Treetop rather than my own hacked-together state machine.